# How do I stop and give the user another attempt at loggin in ---- 3-attempt Login Java Program

Tags: java

What I want help with is that the program will give the user another attempt in typing the email/password correctly while dimishing his attempts if its incorrect :))

here's my code so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class July22_Activity_Lastimosa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String email, password;
        int maxAttempts = 2;
        int index = 0;
        boolean login = false;
        String emailaddress[] = {"jeanroy@gmail.com", "jiromo@gmail.com", "kimisu@gmail.com", "papi@gmail.com", "koi@gmail.com"};
        String passwords[] = {"jeanroy123", "jiromo123", "kimisu123", "papi123", "koi123"};
        String name[] = {"Jean Roy Lastimosa", "Jiromo Lastimosa", "Kimisu Lastimosa", " Papi Lastimosa", " Koi Lastimosa"};
        String username[] = {"Jean", "Jiromo", "Kimisu", "Papi", "Koi"};
        String birthdates[] = {"Dec. 18, 1999", "Jan. 18, 2000", "Feb. 18, 2001", "Mar. 18, 2002", "Apr. 18, 2003"};

        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {

            System.out.print("L O G I N\n");
            System.out.println("\nEmail: ");
            email = input.next();
            System.out.println("Password: ");
            password = input.next();

            for (int x = 0; x <= 3; x++) {
                if (email.equals(emailaddress[0]) == true && password.equals(passwords[0]) == true) {
                    System.out.println("\nName of the user: " + name[0]);
                    System.out.println("Username: " + username[0]);
                    System.out.println("Birthdate" + birthdates[0]);
                    System.out.println("Email address: " + emailaddress[0]);
                    System.out.println("Password: " + passwords[0]);
                    login = true;

                    break;
                }

                if (login == false) {
                    index++;
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println("Incorrect password/username, please try again. You only have " + maxAttempts + " more attempts!");
                    maxAttempts--;

                    if (x >= 2) {
                        System.out.println("3 failed attempts made, exiting now...");
                        System.exit(0);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this. Prefer `scanner.nextLine` where possible as it's less problematic:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class July22_Activity_Lastimosa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String email, password;
        int maxAttempts = 3;
        int index = 0;
        boolean login = false;
        String emailaddress[] = { "jeanroy@gmail.com", "jiromo@gmail.com", "kimisu@gmail.com", "papi@gmail.com",
                "koi@gmail.com" };
        String passwords[] = { "jeanroy123", "jiromo123", "kimisu123", "papi123", "koi123" };
        String name[] = { "Jean Roy Lastimosa", "Jiromo Lastimosa", "Kimisu Lastimosa", "Papi Lastimosa",
                "Koi Lastimosa" };
        String username[] = { "Jean", "Jiromo", "Kimisu", "Papi", "Koi" };
        String birthdates[] = { "Dec. 18, 1999", "Jan. 18, 2000", "Feb. 18, 2001", "Mar. 18, 2002", "Apr. 18, 2003" };

        while (maxAttempts >= 0 && !login) {

            System.out.print("L O G I N\n");
            System.out.println("\nEmail: ");
            email = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Password: ");
            password = input.nextLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < username.length; i++) {
                if (email.equals(emailaddress[i]) == true && password.equals(passwords[i]) == true) {
                    System.out.println("\nName of the user: " + name[i]);
                    System.out.println("Username: " + username[i]);
                    System.out.println("Birthdate" + birthdates[i]);
                    System.out.println("Email address: " + emailaddress[i]);
                    System.out.println("Password: " + passwords[i]);
                    login = true;

                    break;
                }
            }

            if (login == false) {
                index++;
                maxAttempts--;
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Incorrect password/username, please try again. You only have " + maxAttempts
                        + " more attempt(s)!");

                if (maxAttempts == 0) {
                    System.out.println("3 failed attempts made, exiting now...");
                    System.exit(0);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```